# Disappearing invoice journal in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, invoice

Recently had a user issue where an invoice journal was created in Dynamixs AX 2012 and attempted to post, failed-(possible system crash), generated a new sequential Invoice Journal which did post successfully; however, the XML generated that is captured by our Accounts Receivable department was the original INV#. Once I found the table in the AOT I was able to find the sequential database Record ID gap. Is this an issue stemming from the process of our AR software capturing an XML at the wrong point during AX invoice schedule posting or do we have a Dynamics AX issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the software capturing the XML. If you create two journals (1 & 2), then delete 1, you'll probably have a gap in the RecId sequence because you deleted it.

It sounds like the software capturing the XML is not a valid [atomic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability), and it received something in-progress.

Keep in mind this is all totally a guess based on the information you provided.

Comment: and our guesses are in alignment. We use Bottomline for invoice generation and it would seem that it does not capture the XML after the invoice posts, but when the posting process begins. It explains the situation, which has only come up 4-5 times in the last 18 months. I appreciate the insight sir.

Comment: I've used Bottomline before, and if you want to confirm your suspicions, set a breakpoint in `\Classes\BT_DPA_CreateReport\MakeReportFromSrsController` (or `MakeReportFromSRSReportRun` or guess a method that will hit), and disable execution in `CIL` for your user, and posting an invoice should trigger the breakpoint. You might find more information that way.